# Stretching frames using grid layout in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to get stretching to work using Python 2.6.7 with Tkinter. I'd expect the below code to stretch the first button to the width of the second, but both buttons are only as wide as they need to be to fit their text.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from Tkinter import *

win = Frame()
win.grid(sticky=N+S+E+W)

inner_a = Frame(win)
inner_a.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+E+W)
inner_b = Frame(win)
inner_b.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=S+E+W)

Button(inner_a, text='1').grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E+W)
Button(inner_b, text='Some long text').grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E+W)

win.mainloop()
```

By my understanding, the single column in `win` will expand to the width of the largest thing it contains, ie the width of `inner_b`, and then the width of `inner_a`, and thence of the first button, will be that of the second button.

Actually, what happens is the below; the first button is only wide enough to contain "1", not as wide as the second button.

[image: Screen shot: two buttons stacked on top of each other, the first has the single character "1", the second the words "Some long text". The bottom button is considerably wider than the top.]

What do I need to do to get the first button to expand the size of the second?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want widgets to line up in a grid, the first thing to do is make sure they have the same parent. This isn't strictly necessary if all the widgets are the same size or you are only using one column.

Another thing you need to do is give your column a weight. What is happening in your code is that the widget *is* expanding to fill the column, but the column isn't expanding to fill the master. If you give it a weight of 1 it will. You ned to do something like `inner_a.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)`, and then do likewise for `inner_b`.

Comment: Giving the widgets the same direct parent isn't an option; this is a minimal example of the real problem, where having the relevant widgets as direct children really isn't an option. Fixing the weight (for column `0`, not `1` as in your answer) sorted it, though, thanks!

Comment: @me_and: are you aware you can put widgets in a container that is different from its parent? This is a very valuable technique. There is an `in_` option to the grid, pack and place commands to do this.