# Tkinter widget not filling grid

Tags: python, tkinter

I seem to be struggling with grid in Tkinter, I am new to this and have trawled this forum and the web but not found the answer.

I would like the two buttons and the label to fill the grid which has a fixed size of 320 x 240. I initially had trouble with the sticky and having read the net written it in 3 different ways, none of them throw an error but none of them work.

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.setLounge = 21.0
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.lou_dec = tk.Button(self)
        self.lou_dec["text"] = "<"
        self.lou_dec["command"] = self.louDec
        self.lou_dec.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=("N", "S", "E", "W"))

        self.lblLouTemp = tk.Label(self)
        self.lblLouTemp["text"] = self.setLounge
        self.lblLouTemp.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=(tk.N + tk.S + tk.E + tk.W))

        self.lou_inc = tk.Button(self)
        self.lou_inc["text"] = ">"
        self.lou_inc["command"] = self.louInc
        self.lou_inc.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky=(tk.N, tk.S, tk.E, tk.W))

    def louDec(self):
        self.setLounge -= 0.5
        print ("%s" % self.setLounge)
        fo = open("/home/tony/Code/tempreg.txt", "w")
        fo.write("%s" % self.setLounge)
        fo.close()

    def louInc(self):
        self.setLounge += 0.5
        print ("%s" % self.setLounge)
        fo = open("/home/tony/Code/tempreg.txt", "w")
        fo.write("%s" % self.setLounge)
        fo.close()

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Heating Controller")
root.geometry("320x240")
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()`
```

many thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728638/stretching-frames-using-grid-layout-in-python-tkinter) post, it seems that it's necessary to supply a `weight` argument to `rowconfigure` and `columnconfigure` if you want a widget to stretch to fit its environment. In your case, you will have to do this twice - once for the widgets in your frame, and once for the frame itself. Don't forget to make the frame sticky, too.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.setLounge = 21.0
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        master.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid(sticky="news")
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.lou_dec = tk.Button(self)
        self.lou_dec["text"] = "<"
        self.lou_dec["command"] = self.louDec
        self.lou_dec.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=("N", "S", "E", "W"))

        self.lblLouTemp = tk.Label(self)
        self.lblLouTemp["text"] = self.setLounge
        self.lblLouTemp.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=(tk.N + tk.S + tk.E + tk.W))

        self.lou_inc = tk.Button(self)
        self.lou_inc["text"] = ">"
        self.lou_inc["command"] = self.louInc
        self.lou_inc.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky=(tk.N, tk.S, tk.E, tk.W))

        for i in range(1,4):
            self.columnconfigure(i, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

    def louDec(self):
        self.setLounge -= 0.5
        print ("%s" % self.setLounge)
        fo = open("/home/tony/Code/tempreg.txt", "w")
        fo.write("%s" % self.setLounge)
        fo.close()

    def louInc(self):
        self.setLounge += 0.5
        print ("%s" % self.setLounge)
        fo = open("/home/tony/Code/tempreg.txt", "w")
        fo.write("%s" % self.setLounge)
        fo.close()

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Heating Controller")
root.geometry("320x240")
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```